# Prevent ViewPager from always instantiating Fragment at position 0?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I'm using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and `ViewPager`, and the default starting page is 0.  I want mine to start on some arbitary page, say 5.  This is how I display my ViewPager:

```
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewNumber, true);
```

However, the ViewPager is first created at the default position (0), then switched to my desired position (5).  So my fragments are created in this order: 0, 1, 4, 5, 6.

I don't want the fragments at 0 and 1 created at all.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: why not just move whatever fragment you want to be loaded to position 0?

Comment: The ViewPager is the "detail view" of a list in a previous activity.  I want the user to be able to page through the ViewPager in the same order as the list, but it should start centered on the list item they selected.  I still want them to be able to page back and forward and see the appropriate items.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?

Comment: I think this issue has answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21104023/13789930

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Fragment and ViewPager starts always at first position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101865/android-fragment-and-viewpager-starts-always-at-first-position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I achieve this?

Copy the source code of `ViewPager` into your project, refactor it into your own package, and modify the code to suit. Specifically, you would need to modify `setAdapter()` to not attempt to lay out or populate the `ViewPager`, until you manually request that by some new method (e.g., `lisaWouldLikeYouToPopulateNowKThxBye()`).

You *might* be able to get away with subclassing `ViewPager` and overriding `populate()` to not actually do its work based on some flag you hold in your subclass, so that you could avoid populating from your `PagerAdapter` until after your `setCurrentItem()` call.

Or, just leave it alone. It is unclear what benefits you perceive for doing this, let alone whether they would be worth the maintenance headache of your forked `ViewPager`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I thought that this might be a fairly common request -- for example, it's possible to do this when using fragments with tabs.  I guess not.

Comment: @Lisa: "for example, it's possible to do this when using fragments with tabs" -- not that I'm aware of.